# K-Fold Cross Validation: Bias in cross-validated effect size measures?

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, cross-validation, bias

As pointed out by various authors (e.g., Hastie, 2011), K-fold cross-validation has an upward bias of prediction error. I wonder whether the same holds for cross-validated *effect size measures* such as a cross-validated multiple R^2 from multiple linear regression. The literature I could find deals with the case of bias in the prediction error, not averaged/cross-validated effect size measures. So, is there any formal proof or simulation-based evidence that cross-validated effect size measures yield biased estimates?

Comment: By "upward bias", are you referring to under-fitting of the model in case of small data-sets?

Comment: Not exactly. What I actually meant was that averaged / cross-validated R^2 values are consistently larger than the ones obtained from the entire sample of small data-sets. But that might be the same, seen from a different angle.

Comment: It might be. Maybe you can have a look into the CV chapter of [The Elements of statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf), specifically page 243. Here, the authors argue that if data is sparse and the model has a steep learning curve, the CV error might be biased upwards since the individual CV models are trained with less data.

Comment: That was very helpful, thanks. I also found the paper [On Estimating Model Accuracy with Repeated Cross-Validation](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/34528641.pdf) which addresses the question in more detail and also provides evidence for that kind of bias.